# CausesValidation hierarchy with buttons inside a control

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I will see if I can explain this well enough for someone to answer or send me down the right path.

Here goes:

I have built several custom controls; forms, textboxes, checkboxes, etc. One of the Controls is a Navigation Bar that contains buttons like: Top, Next, Find, Add, Delete, etc.

On my Form is the Navigation Bar and several other the custom textboxes, checkboxes, comboboxes, etc. Each of these controls have custom code in the `OnValidating` method.

It appears that the `CausesValidation` property for the container of the Navigation buttons takes precedence over the `CausesValidation` property of the buttons within the bar.

So what I really want to do is turn off the `CausesValidation` of the container and have the controls on the form honor whatever the value of the `CausesValidation` property is for each of the buttons individually.

When I built the Navigation Bar, its base class was `UserControl`. I have tried most of the controls that are Containers and I get similar behavior.

So I am not sure if I should pick a different method (other than `OnValidating`) for each control or if there is some other way to get the validation to occur when the container `CasuesValidation = False`, but `CausesValidation` on the `button = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem.

It turns out the *`Checkbox`* `OnValidating` was firing regardless of whether or not it had focus.  I am not sure why and could not find any reason for it either.  I removed the code in the `OnValidating` method and placed it in `OnClick` and `CheckChanged` which resolved my issue.

I was able to then change the `CausesValidation` property for the *`Container`* of the `Navigation Bar` back to *`false`*.